# Unable to create file on GCP file store

Tags: linux, filesystems, google-cloud-filestore

I got an error message as No space left on device when trying to create a file on GCP file store mount point.

1. I checked there is enough space and inodes available on GCP file store.
2. I can be able to create files and folders on same mount point
3. I got error message specific to file name
4. I also try to find open file using lsof command on same mount point but there is no such deleted

Comment: Have you tried to open all deleted files using [`lsof | grep deleted`](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/troubleshooting#df_and_du_commands_report_different_amounts_of_free_disk_space) and then clearing disk space?

Comment: Meanwhile can you share complete error?

Comment: @RoopaM root@veratos-virtual-appliance-nlp-1-6f47c6b669-xpgbs:/data/NLP-output-directory# touch N56289_text.txt
touch: cannot touch 'N56289_text.txt': No space left on device

Comment: The error could be due to empty files and they might be consuming the `Cloud Filestore` instance’s capacity with their metadata. or having a large amount of files in a single directory, try to split from a single directory to sub-directories

Comment: @RoopaM I can able to create multiple files in same path using touch but not able to create with name 'N56289_text.txt'. Even there is no deleted files after running command  lsof | grep deleted

Comment: Seems like your issue needs internal logs to check the route cause. feel free to contact [google support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub)